# Usage of dwell/hail

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When I describe myself, I normally have to say where I'm from. If I were actually born and raised in Chicago, could I use dwell and/or hail?

> - I *dwell* in Chicago.
> - I *hail* in Chicago.

Comment: This is a question that belongs on English Language Learners

Comment: I hail **from** Chicago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct use of *hail* is *I hail from Chicago.*

The correct use of *dwell* is as you have in your example, but you need not have been born there. If you reside there, you dwell there. To *dwell in* is to inhabit. It is derived from Old Norse *dvelja* ‘delay, tarry, stay.’

Neither word is used very often anymore. People tend to say, *I was born in/I come from* and *I live in* respectively.

Comment: I take it you don't endorse my answer to [your meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/) then. I misinterpreted it at first, but [Mari-Lou's comment](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/answering-questions-in-comments#comment15201_4557), which has several upvotes, says *everybody does it (write answers) **in comments***.